# Is there any way to check which key combinations are not mapped to anything in neovim/vim?

Tags: vim, neovim, neovim-plugin

Occasionally, I map a group of related actions (usually related to a plugin) to a group of key combinations.

I try to use some mnemonics to ease remembering it.
For instance, I added 3 mappings for [overseer](https://github.com/stevearc/overseer.nvim/) plugin (qr, qt, qa) for (Run, Toggle and Quick Action respectively).

When I do that I need to identify which key combinations "are not used" first.
**The question is if there is a way to identify a group of "not used key combinations"** that can be used to map a new set of actions. (*A) (*B)

*A: Is not that I have too many use combinations, but sometimes the existing combinations are embedded in muscle memory, and do not realize that are used until seeing its definition

*B: Understanding that there is an infinite key combination, the intention is to the X most recommended.

Kind of the opposite of this question: [In NeoVim/Vim, how to know all used key combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73841647/in-neovim-vim-how-to-know-all-used-key-combination)

Comment: use leader key for custom mappings. <space> is best for leader key as it can be reached with both hands

Comment: Wise. I still not get used to it... apart from that, I'm left-handed, and the way, I put my hands (probably not the best and not symmetrical) is not straightforward to reach the space bar with my right hand.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the one you gave as example are actually not available: `qr`, `qt`, `qa`, unless you are OK with losing the ability to record macros into registers `r`, `t`, and `a`.

I've maintained [a list of such available pairs](https://gist.github.com/romainl/1f93db9dc976ba851bbb) for a while.

---

The operators `c`, `d`, and `y` expect a motion, like `w`, `e`, etc. The second character in the following pairs is not a motion so it is a NOP and nothing is overridden if we use them in mappings.

```
   cd cm co cp cq cr cs cu cx cy cz
dc    dm       dq dr ds du dx dy dz
yc yd ym yo yp yq yr ys yu yx yz
```

`v` is not an operator but it has similar semantics. There are fewer available pairs, though, because it is possible to use an operator right after `v`.

```
vm vo vq vv vz
```

Vi didn't have anything assigned to `g` so Vim kind of treated the namespace as a dumpster for new two-characters commands. Here are the pairs that are left:

```
gb gc gl gs gy
```

`z` was free, too, and it got the same treatment, with an even worse outcome:

```
zq
```

---

NOTE: The comments in the gist are also worth reading.

NOTE: `gs` is in the list because *I* think it is useless. YMMV.

Comment: Well... this is an awesome example. I use macros very thoroughly without thinking about the shortcut. I didn't see that was for that until you mentioned it.